# Prove that if $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x}=l$ for $b ≠ 0$ then $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{f(bx)}{x}=bl$

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-explanation

$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x}=l$   for   $b ≠ 0$   then $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{f(bx)}{x}=bl$

Comment: without L'Hopital ?, then change variable

Comment: Multiply and divide by $b$ and let $y = bx$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Use the equality

$$\left\vert \frac{f(bx)}{x}-bl \right\vert = b\left\vert \frac{f(bx)}{bx}-l \right\vert$$

Answer (score 1):

You can use the change of variable $bx = y$, getting: $$\lim_{y \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(y)}{y/b} = bl$$

Note that everything is well defined (with $b \in \mathbb{R}-\{0\}$).

Comment: you omitted $l$